# Fix vertical alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, vertical-alignment

I am using a beamer frame in which the top has alternating list items, and the bottom has a picture. The problem is that because of the different number of rows for each item, the picture changes vertical position as I move between list items, as I show in the following code. Does anyone know how to "stick" it in place, at the bottom?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1|only@1> item1 (a single row)
      \item<2|only@2> item2 \\ has 2 rows
      \item<3|only@3> item3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign a defined height to the top minipage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1|only@1> item1 (a single row)
      \item<2|only@2> item2 \\ has 2 rows
      \item<3|only@3> item3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try `\vskip0pt plus 1filll` instead

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[t]{System overview}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item<1|only@1> item1 (a single row)
      \item<2|only@2> item2 \\ has 2 rows
      \item<3|only@3> item3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\vskip0pt plus 1filll
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{picture.jpg}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is what beameruserguide suggests.

Comment: That's excellent. Where does the user guide suggest this if you don't mind me asking? I was unable to find it.

Comment: In my copy it can be found on page 62. (The very last example).

Comment: +1 That is indeed cool (and preferable too my suggestion of explicitly specifying the minipage's height).

Comment: I see, too bad that it does not explain exactly what is going on. (That is, why it is even required, apparently there is some `vfill` generated at the end of the frame, but I can't find it specified anywhere, short of going through the code by hand). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: There are different stretchable spaces with different names, the more `l`'s you add the more priority the space has. I believe you can put 1, 2 or 3 of them. The `plus` in command says to TeX "increase the `0pt` by `vfilll` if you get smaller badness (badness measures how "nice" is the output).