# Align beamer color box at bottom of frame

Tags: beamer, minipage, vertical, colorbox

due to problems trying to make a footnote without number (the objective is to include the source of an image), I tried using beamercolorbox with a tiny font (maybe is not the most correct option, but produces what I want, text without a border).

I read the following links with no sucess:
[link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54180/how-do-i-write-something-at-the-end-of-the-slide-in-beamer)
[link2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41979/fix-vertical-alignment-in-beamer)

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introducción}
  \begin{minipage}[0.9\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}[]{0.5\textwidth}
          texto 1
      \end{column}      
      \begin{column}[]{0.5\textwidth}
         texto 2
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[0.1\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[width=\textwidth,bottom]{}
     {\tiny 
    Fuente: Experimental analysis, modeling and simulation of a solar energy accumulator with paraffin wax as PCM}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

It seems like the height argument of the minipages is not respected. This example contains what I want, an image (here text) at the left, text at the right (because of this I use columns in first minipage), and the 'footnote' at the bootom (wich I can't make to work).
Just to clarify, I read several post asking about alignment of text inside a box, I want the box alig

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: The `beamercolorbox` environment does not provide a `width` option or a `bottom` option...

Comment: The height of a `minipage` is its **second** optional argument: `\begin{minipage}[t][0.9\textheight]{\textwidth}...`

Comment: @PaulGaborit I failed to find a list of the available arguments to beamercolorbox, the bottom option was part of my attempt to align it to the bottom of the frame, I expected an error message for non existent arguments. Putting the height as second optional argument worked, thanks.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @samcarter I don't know how to produce a bottom aligned box with beamer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply stay with your original idea and use a footnote without number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\nonumbernote}[1]{%
  {%
      \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
        \parindent 1em\noindent%
        \raggedright
        \insertfootnotetext\par%
    }
    \footnotetext[42]{#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\nonumbernote{Fuente: Experimental analysis, modeling and simulation of a solar energy accumulator with paraffin wax as PCM}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]