# how can I use vfill in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing

I have 2 slides, for which I want logos to be at the bottom, on the same spot.
I thought I could use `\vfill`, but the logos have different distances from the bottom of the slides.
How can I solve this?
my doc:

```
\title{Compact State Space Representation for Quantum Deep 
Reinforcement Learning with the Help of Auto Encoders}

\author{Elias Brandstetter}



\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[plain]
  \centering
  \normalsize
  \maketitle
  \vfill
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{images/logo_jlu.jpeg}
    \hspace{20mm}
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{images/logo_dfki.jpg}
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}[plain]
  \centering
  \Large 
  Bachelor Thesis\\
  \normalsize
  \vspace{5mm}
  Entry Presentation\\
  \vspace{10mm}
  Examiners:\\
  \vspace{3mm}
  \begin{tabular}{c c c}
   apl. Prof Jens Sören Lange & - & JLU Giessen\\
   Prof. Dr. Dr. h.c. Frank Kirchner & - & DKFI Bremen
  \end{tabular}
  \vfill
  \begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{images/logo_jlu.jpeg}
   \hspace{20mm}
   \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{images/logo_dfki.jpg}
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
\end{document
```

the resulting slides have very different spacing at the bottom:
[image: resulting slides]

Comment: try `\vskip0pt plus 1filll` ... I have found that here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41988/120578 and using with success for years

Comment: As far as I am aware, `\vfil` and `\vfill` are equivalent, if not combined? but changed to latter, for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @koleygr thanks, that worked (: .. can't believe I didn't find that

Comment: Welcome and happy TeXing @eli44 ...